# javascript - keep getting error with multiple equation with words and results

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a result that looks like this

"The volume of the cone 261.66 is greater than the volume of the cylinder 785: false."

```js
console.log("The volume of the cone " +(10 / 3 * (3.14 * (5 **2))) "is greater than the volume of the cylinder " +(10 * (3.14 * (5 **2)))): 261 > 785);
```

EDIT: Thanks for all your help everyone. I can believe I didn't see that I didn't put + and thanks for point out ":" I was so tired and I just wanted to finish I can't believe I wasted all that time getting the math to work just to miss a + and forgot about :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed adding `+` or concatenation after the numerical expressions and `:` should have been in quotes too as its a string. Better yet use templating, both examples below:

```js
// With concatination
console.log("The volume of the cone " + (10 / 3 * (3.14 * (5 ** 2))) + " is greater than the volume of the cylinder " + (10 * (3.14 * (5 ** 2))) + ": " + (261 > 785));

// With templating
console.log(`The volume of the cone ${(10 / 3 * (3.14 * (5 ** 2)))} is greater than the volume of the cylinder ${(10 * (3.14 * (5 ** 2)))}: ${(261 > 785)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be one from below

*String Concatenation*

```js
console.log("The volume of the cone " + (10 / 3 * (3.14 * (5 **2))) + "is greater than the volume of the cylinder " + (10 * (3.14 * (5 **2))) + ":" + (261 > 785));
```

**Please Note** the importance of the paranthesis in `(261 > 785)`. Removing the bracket will throw a `false` as output. Because the string expression in console will be checked against `> 785` if the bracket is removed, that will result in `false` as result

**OR**

*Template Literals*

```js
console.log(`The volume of the cone  ${(10 / 3 * (3.14 * (5 **2)))} is greater than the volume of the cylinder ${(10 * (3.14 * (5 **2)))} : ${261 > 785}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a + and ":"

With template literals

```
console.log(`The volume of the cone ${(10 / 3 * (3.14 * (5 **2)))} is greater than the volume of the cylinder ${(10 * (3.14 * (5 **2)))} : ${261 > 785}`);
```

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)